# Check if data is less than the previous month value in mule4

Tags: mule4

My scenario is to check if the data value is less than the previous month date value.
Suppose current date is 2020-05-01 (YYYY-MM-DD)
and date value coming from the source is 2020-02-01 (YYYY-MM-DD)
I need to ignore this record and set flag value in mule4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dates come as strings, you have to convert them to Dates with the right format pattern. Note that the right pattern is `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. Once it is converted to a Date type then you can extract the [desired part of the date](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#date_decomposition).

I'm not really sure why you need only the month but note that if the year is significant the comparison will be meaningless. You could compare just the dates instead to take into account year, month and day.

Example:

Input:

```
{
    "date1": "2020-05-01",
    "date2": "2020-02-01"
}
```

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
    a: (payload.date1 as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}).month,
    b: (payload.date2 as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}).month,
    c: (payload.date1 as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}).month > (payload.date2 as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}).month
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "a": 5,
  "b": 2,
  "c": true
}
```